# error in function -not GIS - not 2D spatial, which arguments of spatstat

Tags: spatstat

I am using spatstat in R to generate points on a linear network. I had successfully generated a poisson distributed poisson process on a road network.

Now when I want to use the 'nsim', to have more than one realization of the random process, I get an error (using this data) http://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/diva/rds/NLD_rds.zip

```
roads<-readShapeSpatial("NL_rd.shp")
spatstat.roads<-as.psp(roads)
final_roads<-as.linnet(spatstat.roads)

abc<-rpoislpp(0.02/5000,final_roads, nsim=2)
plot(abc)
```

when I use that nsim, I get an error as follows

```
Error in (function (..., check = TRUE, promote = TRUE, demote = FALSE)  : 
  Some arguments of solist() are not 2D spatial objects
```

While it works for one realization, i wanted to draw two realizations to visually compare the randomness. So  i not understand how one realization can be arrived but not two and the error talks of non-2D spatial objects. it is a little cryptic for me.

Could you please clarify on this error and how to resolve it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug.

It will be fixed shortly in [the development version of spatstat](https://github.com/spatstat/spatstat/), version `1.47-0.018` and later.

In the meantime you can get the desired result by using `replicate`, e.g.

```
abc <- replicate(2, rpoislpp(0.02/5000,final_roads), simplify=FALSE)
```

Thank you for drawing this to our attention.

Comment: Thank you. I will try and use the `replicate` and report back.

Comment: Sorry, but replicate did not work for me.  It gives another error. `Error in xy.coords(x, y, xlabel, ylabel, log) : 
  'x' is a list, but does not have components 'x' and 'y' `  when I tried `plot(replicate(2, rpoislpp(0.02/5000,final_roads), simplify=FALSE))` to plot something like a 1 row 2 column matrix plot, similar to what would have been with `nsim`

Comment: I am able to plot them individually, plot(abc[[1]]) and plot(abc[[2]]). Do I miss something in making them a single combined matrix plot? Should I just continue to plot as a regular R matrix plot?

Comment: The `replicate` command just returns a list, whose entries are `lpp` objects in this case. To plot each entry of the list as a separate panel in a multi-panel plot, you could convert the list to a `solist` using `as.solist` and then plot this object. `plot(as.solist(abc))` where `abc` is the result of `replicate`. Anyway, the bug is fixed now in the spatstat development version on GitHub, so you can go back to the original command.

Comment: Thank you for the alert.